# Align divs next to each other using float in PHP

Tags: php, css-tables

**Problem:**

I am trying to align divs next to each other using `float:left` but I can't get it to work. Instead, they are aligning under each other.

**PHP code:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $kriterium .= '<div style="float:left;">'.$i.'</div>';
    $betyg .= '<div style="float:left;">'.$row['RID'].'</div>';

    $mean += $row['RID'];

    $i++;
}

$meanvalue = round ($mean / ($i-1), 2);

$kriterium .= '<div style="float:left;"><b>Medelv&auml;rde</b></div>';
$betyg .= '<div style="float:left;"><b>'.$meanvalue.'</b></div>';

$html .= '
    <div class="table table-condensed table-bordered neutralize">
        <div>
            <b>Kriterium</b>'.$kriterium.'
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Betyg</b>'.$betyg.'
        </div>
    </div>';
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Question:**

What is wrong with the CSS code that needs to be modified so that divs are aligned like columns next to each other?

Comment: If you want a  table, why are you using floated divs?  Why not use a table?

Comment: I'm using mPDF and border-radius is not supported for the table-element, otherwise I would have used it. Therefore, I need to work with divs instead.

Comment: Could you create a demo in jsfiddle.net with the output that's generated from your PHP in the browser?

Comment: The data comes from a database but there is a demo: http://screencast.com/t/SLeVzElh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a width for each div.  The width of the first div will be wider than the width of the other divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Kexx</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    div.table-bordered > div  {
      width:420px;
    }
    div.table-bordered > div > div.c {
      width:94px;
    }
    div.table-bordered > div > div {
      float:left;
      width:24px;
    }
    div.table-bordered div {
      border:1px solid #333;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table table-condensed table-bordered neutralize">
      <div>
        <div class='c'><b>Kriterium</b></div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <br style='clear:both;'/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class='c'> <b>Betyg</b></div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>D</div>
        <br style='clear:both;'/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zv7Dp/

Answer (score 0):

try giving position as relative , btw , if you have a separate style sheet , you can define a class and put all style under one class , any way I still prefer a html table than this , and you can find as many as css table styles by googling !